# I have a question about running an Ethereum GETH client node

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, full-node, ds-math-sub-underflow

If a specific node uses a version of the GETH client where it doesn't check for the users Ether balance when sending Ether, what happens? Would the node just accept a transaction where the user doesn't have enough balance? Would that lead to an underflow with Ether balances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,before being being added to the blockchain other node's/ validator's will also verify whether the transaction is legit.

The validity of that  particular transaction is not checked only at originating node